# C program prints 1 twice in a while loop, why?

Tags: c

Code snippet

````
```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  short int a;
  scanf("%hd", &a);
  while (a != 5) {
    printf("%hd\n", a);
    a++;
  }
  return 0;
}
````

The output of this code is:

Code snippet

```
1
1
2
3
4
```

I am expecting the output to be:

Code snippet

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

But why is the output different from what I am expecting?

I have tried the following:

- I have checked the syntax of the code. It is correct.
- I have run the code on different compilers. The output is the same on all compilers.
- I have tried different values for `a`. The output is the same for all values of `a`.

Comment: What are you inputting? Is it `1` by any chance? That is, are you sure that first `1` isn't what you have typed in?

Comment: Maybe print some extra output after `scanf` to make it clear what is printed when. I would guess your are typing the first `1` yourself as the input.

Comment: Run the program with `echo 1 | ./your_program` and then you'll not see the first `1`.

Comment: Sidenote: Your `main` declaration is wrong. It should be `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`. Also, always check that `scanf` succeeds: `if(scanf("%hd", &a) == 1) { /* success */ }` - finally, remove unused variables, like `i`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo "main declaration is wrong." --> Maybe or maybe not as C allows "or in some other implementation-defined manner".  IAC, certainly not portable and should be avoided.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica True that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first "1" is your input. 
I tried to run the same code and that is what I observed the first "1" is the input I gave and then the code prints from 1 to 4.

Answer (score 0):

@Red Sky is right, the first one is your input,
[image: Please take a look]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of plain text. Just copy and paste the output as formatted text into the question. Also the normal way to agree with some answer is to upvote it isntead of writing another answer basically telling the same.

Comment: @Gerhardh  In future, I  will keep this in Mind.